# Configured SSH Key For Git But Still Unsuccessful

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have [followed the steps](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) to configure ssh key for my git account. **However I am still unsuccessful**. Here is a transcript.

```
[John@dev gitRepo]$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi JohnDoe! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
[John@dev gitRepo]$ git remote update
Fetching origin
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

As I understand the message in response for ssh attempt is a *success*. However I should not be prompted for username and password after correctly setting up ssh keys.

The repo is properly setup / cloned earlier as I can access the git account using username and password in that repo.

I appreciate your time and response to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your remote is still set to HTTP. You need to remove that origin and add the SSH origin to start using ssh.

Answer (score 1):

SSH key is for git: protocol, e.g. "url" must look like:

```
git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

it looks to me, you are trying https:// protocol